# Can't open file manager after 24 hr continuous use of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

If I use my Ubuntu system for more than 24 hrs, the file manager closes automatically. And if I try to open it again, it opens and closes immediately.

I tried to open it using the command `sudo nautilus`, but that returns

```
Maximum number of clients reached
** (nautilus:31308): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Maximum number of clients reached
(nautilus:31308): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Unable to open display ':0' 
when setting background pixmap

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please don't use `sudo nautilus`. You can use `sudo -H nautilus` instead if you *really* need to launch nautilus as root, but there's nothing in your question that indicates you needed root privileges.